# Can we chain multiple InternalResourceViewResolver

Tags: spring-mvc

I am trying to implement a fall back mechanism in spring MVC, where controller will return view name suppose viewName and using XML configuration, is it possible that view resolver first look for viewName.jsp and if not found then viewName.html

I  don't want to write any custom view resolver. is it possible ?

Comment: No you cannot. The `InternalResourceViewResolver` simply generates a URL to forward (or redirect) to. It doesn't check if the resource actually exists. There can only be one `InternalResourceViewResolver` and it has to be the last in the chain (as it will always resolve to a view).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in Mkyong....you can use set order for how view resolver will follow. As 0th will be called first and 1st will be called second and so on.. I am posting the link for this. I think this will help you.

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/configure-multiple-view-resolvers-priority-in-spring-mvc/